# How can I calculate the maximum current a circuit needs?

Tags: current, maximum-ratings

I want to add a fuse to a self-designed circuit, but for that I need the maximum current of the circuit. In this circuit I have some ICs, some resistors, some LEDs and some capacitors. When I want to calculate the maximum current for this circuit, is my approach correct so simply take the maximum current each IC wants (according to data sheets), and then add them up? Or do I miss something with this approach? Unfortunately the other answers (as far as I saw) are not valid for my problem.

Comment: Depending how far you want to get to the reality adding up, doing a measurement or simulating (all with adding a safety margin) may work.

Comment: How can I simulate ICs (with which program)? Measurement is not possible, after the circuit has not been built yet.

Comment: What does the fuse protect?

Comment: @Andyaka: According to Olin protecting ICs is useless, and therefore I was already wondering if I should use a fuse, or if I shouldn't (current is power-supply-limited).

Comment: That was my point so maybe you are trying to prevent a fire or cables burning or something that is hazardous to life or a building?

Comment: @Andyaka: Yep, that was one of my reasons to think about implementing a fuse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding all the worst case currents gets you your worst case current.  Unless you need to trim the fuse as tight as possible to your actuall current, go with a little margin above this worst case.

Plain old melting-link fuses aren't for dealing with a little over current.  They are for a catastrophic condition where there is so much current that something would break, catch fire, or the like.

These kind of fuses aren't for making sure a 1 A circuit doesn draw more than 1.1 A, for example.  If that's what you're trying to do, you need a electronic fuse, possibly with a passive fuse as backup for the the really catastrophic case.  Take a look at the datasheet of a melting-link fuse.  You will see they have a wide tolerance and relatively slow response.

Comment: But I only have to add the currents the ICs draw (after they are driving all the other stuff)? And what is "a little margin"? 10%? 25%? Thanks!

Comment: Pay attention to Olin. You cannot use fuses the way you seem to think you can. In this case a little margin is 100 to 200%. Furthermore, fuses are far too slow to keep ICs from self-destruction.

Comment: Would I even need a fuse for a circuit driven with 5V/max 1A (power-supply limited), where the worst case current is at 900 mA? If I design the fuse according to you for 1.8 A, this limit will never reached, and therefore the fuse is useless.

Comment: @arc: Unless you have some unusual case, it doesn't sound like there is a point to a fuse here.  The power supply should already be limiting the current.  Since even a dead short across the power supply shouldn't cause any harm, what do you think a fuse will protect against?

Comment: It was a suggestion from another designer to add a fuse, but after thinking a bit about it I see that it is not neccessary. But would 5V/1A already be unsafe in regarding of fire?

Comment: @arc: Yes, you can cause a fire with less than that, but that is the case with many circuits.  The same voltage/current *could* start a fire is designed to do so, but this is very very unlikely for a ordinary circuit that draws 1 A at 5 V.  In cases where this possibility is significant enough, you usually enclose the circuit in a box and then make sure there is nothing in there to sustain a fire.  Even if you managed to concetrate the 5 W at a small point, you're still not going to get the fiberglass PCB and most electronic parts to catch fire.

Comment: @OlinLathrop: The circuit will be enclosed in a steel case, with around 1cm-thick walls. I think that should stop a fire ignited by the circuit.